# Getting an acknowledgment on server send/emit

Tags: socket.io

In the socket.io acknowledgement example we see a client's send/emit being called back with the server's response. Is the same functionality available in the reverse direction - i.e. how does the server confirm client reception for a send/emit from the server? It would be nice to have a send/emit callback even just to indicate reception success. Didn't see this functionality documented anywhere...
Thanks!

Comment: OK, tested it and it appears to be symmetrical.... (too bad docs are unclear on this). However, while testing I hit another issue: if client disconnects prior to sending a response, the emit/send callback on the sender never gets fired. Seems to me that the API may be improved if the callback mechanism be modified to include an error parameter, e.g.: socket.emit('ferret', 'tobi', function (**err**, data) {.......

Comment: I posted a direct question regarding my latest issue here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578134/reliable-messaging-under-socket-io), please disregard this previous Q, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Looking in the [socket.io source](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L115) I found that indeed ACKs are supported for server-sent messages (but not in broadcasts!) (lines 115-123 of *socket.io/lib/socket.js*):

```
if ('function' == typeof args[args.length - 1]) {
    if (this._rooms || (this.flags && this.flags.broadcast)) {
        throw new Error('Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting');
    }

    debug('emitting packet with ack id %d', this.nsp.ids);
    this.acks[this.nsp.ids] = args.pop();
    packet.id = this.nsp.ids++;
}
```

An example of how the ack should work (not tested):

```
// server-side:
io.on('msg', (data, ackCallback) => {
  console.log('data from client', data);
  ackCallback('roger roger');
});

// client-side:
socket.emit('msg', someData, (answer) => {
  console.log('server\'s acknowledgement:', answer);
});
```

Comment: Any chance you can post the syntax for how the client would send the acknowledgement when listening for an event? From the documentation (https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-on-eventname-callback), it says that client-side socket.on() only accepts two arguments, the eventName and the callBack with the server sent data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can send a response back to the server from the Client(as acknowledgment )

According to new documentation of socket(4.x)

Server-side

```
let dataToSend={
test:"fromServer"
}

socket.timeout(5000).emit("my-event",dataToSend, (err, response) => {
  if (err) {
    // the other side did not acknowledge the event in the given delay
  } else {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

Cleint- side

```
           socket.on("my-event", (data, callback) => {
// any logic for data(that data come from server i.e { test:"fromServer"  }
      callback({ test: "test" });
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to be 100% sure the reception success, just add ack call is not enough because we also need to know whether the ack call is run or not.

[The socket.io 3.0 document](https://socket.io/docs/v3/emitting-events/) add this timeout example to show how to do that. But the timeout value is the tricky one.

```
const withTimeout = (onSuccess, onTimeout, timeout) => {
  let called = false;

  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    if (called) return;
    called = true;
    onTimeout();
  }, timeout);

  return (...args) => {
    if (called) return;
    called = true;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    onSuccess.apply(this, args);
  }
}

socket.emit("hello", 1, 2, withTimeout(() => {
  console.log("success!");
}, () => {
  console.log("timeout!");
}, 1000));
```