args[1] is received as null instead of socket acknowledgment callback
Problem:
Emitting event from server along with the callback and expecting client to trigger callback as the event received to acknowledge the server. Client is getting args[1] as null when is should be a callback.
Steps:
setup "socket.io-client": "^2.0.0" in react  just to test if callback is emitting from server, in this test code, callback received.
server:
 const sendWithRetry = async (msg, attempts = 0, retries, options = {}) => {
    
    let timer;
    attempts++;
    const waitDelay = parseInt(options.waitDelay) || parseInt(global.settingss.socket_ack_wait_time) || 5000;
    const retryCount = parseInt(retries) || parseInt(global.settingss.socket_ack_failure_retries) || 3;

    const socket = socketIO.sockets.connected[msg.socketId];
    if(socket) {
        const response = await new Promise((resolve) => {

            timer = setTimeout(() => resolve(null), waitDelay); // Timeout occurred

            socket.emit(msg.eventName, msg.response, function(ack) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                resolve(ack); // Resolve with client acknowledgment
            });
        });

        if (response && response.success) {
            return response; 
        } else if (!response && attempts < retryCount) {
            console.log(`No acknowledgment, retrying...`, attempts);
            clearTimeout(timer);
            return sendWithRetry(msg, attempts, retryCount, options); // Recursively retry
        } else {
            console.log('Acknowledgment not received after retries. sending push')
            clearTimeout(timer);
            sendPush(msg);
        }
    }}


client
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            Log.d("hello","helloTesting::"+new Gson().toJson(args));
            String serverResponse = args[0].toString();
            Utils.redLog(ApiTags.BOOKING_CONVERSION_NOTIFICATION, serverResponse);
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(serverResponse)) {
                try {
                    BookingConversion response = new Gson().fromJson(serverResponse, BookingConversion.class);
                    mCallback.onBookingConversion(response);
                }catch (Exception ignored){
                }
            }
            if (args.length > 1 && args[1] instanceof io.socket.emitter.Emitter.Listener) {
                Log.d("hello","helloTesting::1::"+new Gson().toJson(args[1]));
                Emitter.Listener ack = (Emitter.Listener) args[1];
                //ack.call("Acknowledgment received!");
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonObject.put("success",true);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                ack.call(jsonObject);
            }
        }



server socket.io version "socket.io": "^2.0.3",
client version io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0
cannot upgrade versions as this is legacy code up and running on prod. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

You can try workarounds like not using callback,but a separate function to send message. I think you are not having compatability issue 1.x client 2.x server is compatible

Try setup "socket.io-client": "^1.0.0" in react to test if callback emitting from server is receivable by 1.x framework. That would debug a lot!

However you can consider upgrading both server,client, there is no documentation for 1.x client except one I linked, that doesn't talk on callback compatibility. Further this states 1.x 2.x is not compatible although it is talking about js client. You can try implementation 'io.socket:socket.io-client:2.0.1' in gradle right?

@redoc I tried sending String instead of callback and it successfully received. There is no react socket client version 1.0.0 in react. though I have tried with very old one as I mentioned in my question. Cannot really update version as this is legacy code and will have do a lot of changes. It is maven btw.

Please see this link for help on server ack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568467/getting-an-acknowledgment-on-server-send-emit. Your client code seems to be correct; it's the server with timer that seems to be the issue.

Turned out that, it was never socket issue. GSON was unable to parse callback at the second index, marking that null.
Log.d("hello","helloTesting::"+new Gson().toJson(args));
seems like functions are not serlizables as Objects or other primitives in Java
